# Programmatically adding an item to a CardView

Tags: android, android-cardview, android-tablelayout

I have the following XML

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
                app:cardElevation="2dp"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:background="@drawable/border_bottom"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:background="@drawable/round"
                            android:id="@+id/image"
                            android:scaleType="fitXY"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                            android:layout_width="50dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:padding="2dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:gravity="center|start"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:id="@+id/tv_billtype"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:paddingBottom="3dp"/>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <TableLayout
                        android:background="@drawable/border_bottom"
                        android:id="@+id/table_items"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

As you can see there are `TableLayout` and `LinearLayout` in `CardView`. When I programmatically add a row in the TableLayout, LinearLayout is below TableLayout and I can't see LinearLayout.
It's working like `FrameLayout`. When I remove CardView from my code it work correctly.

```
 TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table_items);
    tableLayout.invalidate();
    tableLayout.removeAllViews();
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        TableRow trFinish = (TableRow) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.row_billdetail_product, null);
        TextView name, price, quantity;
        name = (TextView)trFinish.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        price = (TextView)trFinish.findViewById(R.id.tv_price);
        quantity = (TextView)trFinish.findViewById(R.id.tv_quantity);

        JSONObject obj = null;
        obj = array.getJSONObject(i);
        name.setText(obj.getString("Name"));
        price.setText(obj.getString("Price"));
        quantity.setText(obj.getString("Qty") + " x " + obj.getString("PriceUnit"));

        tableLayout.addView(trFinish);
    }
```

How to add it correctly?

My Whole XML. Althought not complete.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:weightSum="10"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        android:fillViewport="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
                app:cardElevation="2dp"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:background="@drawable/border_bottom"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <ImageView
                            android:background="@drawable/round"
                            android:id="@+id/image"
                            android:scaleType="fitXY"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                            android:layout_width="50dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:padding="2dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:gravity="center|start"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:id="@+id/tv_billtype"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:paddingBottom="3dp"/>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <TableLayout
                        android:background="@drawable/border_bottom"
                        android:id="@+id/table_items"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> 

                    <TableLayout
                        android:background="@drawable/border_bottom"
                        android:id="@+id/table_prices"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
                app:cardElevation="2dp"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/note_title"
                            android:scaleType="fitXY"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                            android:layout_width="50dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:padding="2dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:gravity="center|start"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:id="@+id/note_contents"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:paddingBottom="3dp"/>


                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <!--there is a two button-->
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this xml and let me know if it working or not

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
            app:cardElevation="2dp"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:background="@drawable/border_bottom"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <ImageView
                        android:background="@drawable/round"
                        android:id="@+id/image"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:padding="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:gravity="center|start"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:id="@+id/tv_billtype"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:paddingBottom="3dp"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <TableLayout
                    android:background="@drawable/border_bottom"
                    android:id="@+id/table_items"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

           </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: thanks it works. So i need Linear layout in Cardview. It become so much nested.

Comment: great please accept the answer. If you want to make to simple then you have to review your design. or show me the actual design and i will suggest you the correct layout design

Comment: just add your xml design in your question and i will have a look.

Comment: You can try removing linear layout under the scrollview. just keep your cardview under the scrollview.